# How to handle XmlWriter.Create in a subclass

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I need to change the behaviour of XmlWriter for my project to change the way that empty xml elements are serialised. Currently, my code uses XmlWriter and XmlSerializer like so:

```cs
public string Serialize(object o)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    ...

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, o);

    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

When serializing my xml, empty elements are being serialized to `<emptyElement/>`, but I need the xml to serialize empty elements to `<emptyElement></emptyElement>`. The best solution I've found for this was stated in this a Microsoft forum years ago: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/979315cf-6727-4979-a554-316218ab8b24/xml-serialize-empty-elements?forum=xmlandnetfx

> The faster and safer way of doing this is by writing your own subclass of the XmlWriter and give it to XmlSerializer.
>
> YourXmlWriter would aggregate standard one and would translate all WriteEndElement() calls to WriteFullEndElement() calls.

I've tried writing my own subclass of XmlWriter, overriding the two methods I need to override:

```cs
public abstract class CustomXmlWriter : XmlWriter
    {
        public override void WriteEndElement()
        {
            WriteFullEndElement();
        }

        public override Task WriteEndElementAsync()
        {
            return WriteFullEndElementAsync();
        }
    }
```

In theory, I believe this should work. However, when trying to use the code, I'm coming up against a brick wall around [XmlWriter.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.create?view=netframework-4.8). I cannot cast the resulting XmlWriter to my CustomXmlWriter for obvious reasons, and I can't override the method as it's a static method.

How am I meant to deal with the static Create method? The only other way I can think of doing this is to scrap the idea of my own CustomXmlWriter, and to simply manipulate the string at the end of my method, but this feels very wrong. I don't know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible, or if there is a simple setting somewhere that I cannot seem to find anywhere.

Comment: The XML specification allows for null elements to have only one tag.  I would recommend fixing the software that requires two tags for a null element.

Comment: @jdweng I completely agree. We're currently working to see if that's possible, but in the short-term we're trying to find a fix through forcing the two tags on the XML in the first place

Comment: I may be easier for short term to use regex, although I never recommend using regex on xml or html.

Answer (score 1):

Try following Regex as a temporary fix.  The variable input can be the entire xml string and it will replace every occurrence. :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string input = "<emptyElement/>";
            string patternNullTag = @"\<(?'tagname'\w+)/\>";
            string output = Regex.Replace(input, patternNullTag, ReplaceNullElement);
        }
        static string ReplaceNullElement(Match match)
        {
            string tagname = match.Value.Replace("<", "").Replace("/>", "");
            string newElement = "<" + tagname + ">" + "</" + tagname + ">";
            return newElement;
        }
```